# Filtrar array cuyo dia de pago se acerque mas al dia actual

Tags: javascript

```
    [{
    "corte_id": "1",
    "dia_comienzo": "10",
    "dia_pago": "15",
    "dia_finalizacion": "19"
    },{
    "corte_id": "2",
    "dia_comienzo": "27",
    "dia_pago": "30",
    "dia_finalizacion": "4"
    }]
```

---

*Este es el array de momento solo tengo dos posiciones, pero quiciera dejarlo mantenible para agregar más dias en un futuro he intentado lo siguiente:*

```
    const getCut = response.data.find(
      corte => Math.abs(corte.dia_comienzo - date.getDate()) >= 0
        && Math.abs(corte.dia_comienzo - date.getDate()) <= 6
    )
```

- 

Pero no me parece muy correcto ya que funciona cuando los dias actuales son iguales o cercanos a los dias de comienzo y finalizacion*

Answer (score 1):

Una sugerencia que puede resolver el problema es utilizar una función recursiva.

La función `encontrar` se llamará recursivamente y su objetivo es recorrer todo el array y localizar el objeto con el día de pago más cercano al día actual.

Si la diferencia actual es menor que la diferencia más cercana o si `corteMasCercano` es nulo, se actualizarán los valores de `corteMasCercano` y `diferenciaCercana`, y se invocará de forma recursiva la función `encontrar` con el array reducido. Si no hay diferencia actual menor que la diferencia más cercana, la función `encontrar` seguirá recorriendo el array reducido manteniendo los valores anteriores de `corteMasCercano` y `diferenciaCercana`.

```js
function encontrar(array, diaActual, corteMasCercano = null, diferenciaCercana ) {
    if (array.length === 0) {
      return corteMasCercano;
    }
  
    const corte = array[0];
    const diaPago = Number(corte.dia_pago);
    const diferenciaActual = Math.abs(diaPago - diaActual);
  
    if (diferenciaActual < diferenciaCercana || corteMasCercano === null) {
      return encontrar(array.slice(1), diaActual, corte, diferenciaActual);
    } else {
      return encontrar(array.slice(1), diaActual, corteMasCercano, diferenciaCercana);
     
    }
  }


const datos =  
[{
"corte_id": "1",
"dia_comienzo": "10",
"dia_pago": "15",
"dia_finalizacion": "19"
},{
"corte_id": "2",
"dia_comienzo": "27",
"dia_pago": "30",
"dia_finalizacion": "4"
}]


  
  const fecha = new Date();
 
  const corteMasCercano = encontrar(datos, fecha.getDate());
  console.log(corteMasCercano.corte_id);
```

La respuesta es que el ID 1 se debe a que el día de pago es el 15 y es más cercano al día actual en comparación con el otro corte.

El detalle es que la función `encontrar` encuentra el día de pago que está más cerca del día actual.

Por ejemplo

**ID: 1**

- Día de inicio: 10
- Día de pago: 15
- Día de finalización: 19

**ID: 2**

- Día de inicio: 27
- Día de pago: 30
- Día de finalización: 4

**el cálculo** *:*
**(**  *Día actual*   `4`  **)**

**ID: 1**

- `Día de pago`: 15
- Diferencia: ( `15 - 4` ) = 11

**ID: 2**

- `Día de pago`: 30
- Diferencia: ( `30 - 4` ) = 26

El `ID 1` está más cerca del día actual que el ID 2.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta me ha dado un panorama mejor acerca de como atacar el problema provare el metodo y comento si me funciono como espero... excelente noche

Answer (score 0):

Por ejemplo hoy es 4 de Julio y el día de pago es el 25, debemos comparar contra:

- El 25 de este mes (Julio)
- El 25 del mes pasado (Junio)
- El 25 del próximo mes (Agosto)

**¿Por qué?**

Porque si estamos a 4 y el día de pago es 25 la fecha más cercana es el mes pasado.

Pero si estuviéramos a 22 sería este mes.

Y si hoy fuera 30 y el día de pago fuera el 1ro, la fecha más cercana seria el próximo mes.

Entonces debemos obetener estas 3 fechas (mesAnterior, mesActual, mesPosterior), compararlas contra el día actual y quedarnos con el menor

Con este algoritmo realizamos un ordenamiento al array de los datos, quedando en primer lugar (índice 0) el más cercano

```js
let datos =  [
{ "dia_pago": "25"},
{ "dia_pago": "15"},
{ "dia_pago": "1"},
{ "dia_pago": "10"},
{ "dia_pago": "30"},
{ "dia_pago": "6"},
{ "dia_pago": "18"},
{ "dia_pago": "4"},
];

//dia actual
let date = new Date();

//algoritmo que obtiene la diferencia entre el dia actual y los meses anterior, actual y posterior. Devolviendo la menor diferencia entre ellos
function getDias(now, dia){
  if(now.getDate() == dia) return 0;

  let mesAnterior = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() - 1, dia);
  let mesActual = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), dia);
  let mesPosterior = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() +1, dia);
  return Math.min(
    Math.abs(now - mesAnterior),
    Math.abs(now - mesActual),
    Math.abs(now - mesPosterior)
  );
}

//ordenamos el array
datos.sort((a,b) => getDias(date,a.dia_pago) - getDias(date,b.dia_pago));

console.log(datos);

//el mas cercano queda siempre primero
console.log("Día mas cercano", datos[0]);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, verificare nuevamente la idea en verdad fue de mucha ayuda espero me funcione. Excelente noche...